# Restcomm SMSC deployment: SMPP fails to bind

Tags: ant, sms-gateway, restcomm, ss7

I want to deploy Restcomm SMSC. I have downloaded its binary release and running SMSC in simulator mode. I am not using any digital card as I want to work with SIGTRAN and user guide states that in order to use ss7 with IP connectivity (SIGTRAN) , card is not required. Now I start following

1. SMSC in simulator
2. jss7 simulator
3. smpp simulator

also i do 'ant client' with smpp-load module but the build fails with error. 
**[java] Error: Could not find or load main class org.mobicents.protocols.smpp.load.Client**

Also, I am still unable to understand the message flow despite reading the guide. The screenshots in the user guide is using telscale SMSC which is feature-rich than restcomm SMSC. Kindly guide me

Thanks

Comment: Today SMSC fails to deploy. The error is ** 'Failure invoking 'InstallDeployableUnitAction[file:/home/spirit/restcomm-smsc-7.4.154/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/simulator/deploy/smsc-services-du-7.4.154.jar/]'**

Comment: Solved now. Replace javassist jar in folder <your directory>/restcomm-smsc-7.3.153/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib